# Optimizing smoosh() method further

Tags: java, array

Part I of this [question](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/hw/hw3/readme.pdf) says:

> Fill in the `smoosh()` method in the `Homework3` class so that it performs as indicated in the comment. Your solution should not use linked lists, nor should it use your `squish()` method.

Here is the below code written for `smoosh()`, in more than 14 lines. Modular testing is done for this method `smoosh()`.

```
public class Homework3 {

  /**
   *  smoosh() takes an array of ints.  On completion the array contains
   *  the same numbers, but wherever the array had two or more consecutive
   *  duplicate numbers, they are replaced by one copy of the number.  Hence,
   *  after smoosh() is done, no two consecutive numbers in the array are the
   *  same.
   *
   *  Any unused elements at the end of the array are set to -1.
   *
   *  For example, if the input array is [ 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 3 3 3 1 1 0 ],
   *  it reads [ 0 1 0 3 1 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ] after smoosh()
   *  completes.
   *
   *  @param ints the input array.
   **/

    public static void smoosh(int[] a) {
     // Fill in your solution here.  (Ours is fourteen lines long, not counting
     // blank lines or lines already present in this file.)
       int currentPointer = 1;
       int i, j = 0;
       for(i =0; i < a.length; i++){
          int flag = 0;
          for(j = currentPointer; j < a.length; j++)
             if(a[j] != a[i])
             {
                a[i+1] = a[j];
                currentPointer = ++j;
                flag = 1;
                break;
             }
          if(j == a.length){
             if(flag == 1)
                i+=2;
             else
                i += 1;
             for(int k = i; k < a.length; k++)
                a[k] = -1;
             break;
          }
      }
  }

  /**
   *  stringInts() converts an array of ints to a String.
   *  @return a String representation of the array.
   **/

  private static String stringInts(int[] ints) {
    String s = "[  ";
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
      s = s + Integer.toString(ints[i]) + "  ";
    }
    return s + "]";
  }

  /**
   *  main() runs test cases on your smoosh and squish methods.  Prints summary
   *  information on basic operations and halts with an error (and a stack
   *  trace) if any of the tests fail.
   **/

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result;
    int i;


    System.out.println("Let's smoosh arrays!\n");

    int[] test1 = {3, 7, 7, 7, 4, 5, 5, 2, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5};
    System.out.println("smooshing " + stringInts(test1) + ":");
    smoosh(test1);
    result = stringInts(test1);
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals(
            "[  3  7  4  5  2  0  8  5  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  ]"),
                      "BAD SMOOSH!!!  No cookie.");

    int[] test2 = {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3};
    System.out.println("smooshing " + stringInts(test2) + ":");
    smoosh(test2);
    result = stringInts(test2);
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals(
            "[  6  3  6  3  6  3  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  ]"),
                      "BAD SMOOSH!!!  No cookie.");

    int[] test3 = {4, 4, 4, 4, 4};
    System.out.println("smooshing " + stringInts(test3) + ":");
    smoosh(test3);
    result = stringInts(test3);
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  4  -1  -1  -1  -1  ]"),
                      "BAD SMOOSH!!!  No cookie.");

    int[] test4 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    System.out.println("smooshing " + stringInts(test4) + ":");
    smoosh(test4);
    result = stringInts(test4);
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  ]"),
                      "BAD SMOOSH!!!  No cookie.");

   } /* end main*/
}/* end Homework3 class */
```

**`TestHelper`**

```
public class TestHelper {

  /**
   *  verify() checks an invariant and prints an error message if it fails.
   *  If invariant is true, this method does nothing.  If invariant is false,
   *  the message is printed, followed by a dump of the program call stack.
   *
   *  @param invariant  the condition to be verified
   *  @param message  the error message to be printed if the invariant fails to
   *                  hold true.
   **/

  static void verify(boolean invariant, String message) {
    if (!invariant) {
      System.out.println("*** ERROR:  " + message);
      Thread.dumpStack();
    }
  }
}
```

Test case output:

> ```
> Let's smoosh arrays!
>
> smooshing [  3  7  7  7  4  5  5  2  0  8  8  8  8  5  ]:
> [  3  7  4  5  2  0  8  5  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  ]
> smooshing [  6  6  6  6  6  3  6  3  6  3  3  3  3  3  3  ]:
> [  6  3  6  3  6  3  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  ]
> smooshing [  4  4  4  4  4  ]:
> [  4  -1  -1  -1  -1  ]
> smooshing [  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  ]:
> [  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  ]
> ```

Can you please help me guide to squeeze `smoosh()` to 14 lines?

Please provide comments on readability vs optimization for an existing solution of the `smoosh()` method.

Note: This is online self learning [course](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/) from UOC berkeley.

Comment: I don't know why the number of lines matter to you, but they shouldn't. Nothing stops you from throwing all the code into a single line anyway which just goes to show how meaningless LoC are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code advances an index until it finds an element that is different
from the current element `a[i]` and copies that to `a[i+1]`. The "filling"
part is bit involved because you have to distinguish whether an element
was copied into `a[i+1]` or not (your flag).

To work towards the given line limit, you use "non-trivial" `for` and `if`
statements without braces `{ ... }`, which does not increase the
legibility and is error-prone (if more statements are added to
the for/if-expression later).

It becomes simpler if you think the other way around: Copy the current
element from the original position to the target position first, then
advance the original position until a different element is found.
This will copy some elements unnecessarily to itself, but leads to the following
function (13 lines in total without the comments) which should be self-explaining:

```
public static void smoosh(int[] a) {
    int originalPos = 0;
    int targetPos = 0;
    while (originalPos < a.length) {
        // Copy (and remember) one element to the correct position:
        int currentElement = a[targetPos++] = a[originalPos++];
        // Advance originalPos until a different element is found:
        while (originalPos < a.length && a[originalPos] == currentElement) {
            originalPos++;
        }
    }
    // Fill remaining elements:
    while (targetPos < a.length) {
        a[targetPos++] = -1;
    }
}
```

(Everything apart from the `smoosh()` function itself seems to be prescribed
by the given homework skeleton, so I am not going to comment on that.)

Comment: i think, i am not capable of thinking this quality. Because this program is following the same flow, but code looks more elegant. Depressed!!!

Answer (score 3):

Your `flag` variable practically will only be `0` and `1`. You can switch to using a `boolean` instead:

```
boolean flag = false;
for(j = cP; j < a.length; j++){
    if(a[j] != a[i])
    {
            a[i+1] = a[j];
            cP = ++j;
            flag = true;
            break;
    }
}

if(j == a.length){
    if (flag)
        i+=2;
    else
        i += 1;
    for(int k = i; k < a.length; k++)
        a[k] = -1;
    break;
}
```

Don't concatenate `String`s in a loop, it is more efficient to use a `StringBuilder`:

```
String s = "[  ";
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
  s = s + Integer.toString(ints[i]) + "  ";
}
return s + "]";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("[  ");
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    builder.append(ints[i]).append("  ");
}
return builder.append(']').toString();
```

For more readable code you can even switch to a for-each loop:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("[  ");
for (int element : ints)
    builder.append(element).append("  ");
return builder.append(']').toString();
```

> Is this solution for smoosh() method readable?

You can further improve the readability by:

```
Commenting through your code
if(j == a.length){ // This part allows the loop to increment
    if(flag == 1)  // the field "i" usefully.
        i+=2;
    else
        i += 1;
    for(int k = i; k < a.length; k++)
        a[k] = -1;
    break;
}
Using more descriptive variable names
int quantifier = 1;
int elementIndex, nextElementIndex = 0;
```

> If yes, Can you please help me guide to squeeze `smoosh()` to 14 lines?

Sure, that means *code golfing*, but here have code (12 lines):

```
public static void smoosh(int[] a) {
    // Fill in your solution here.  (Ours is fourteen lines long, not counting
    // blank lines or lines already present in this file.)
    int cP = 1, j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        boolean flag = false;
        for (j = cP; j < a.length; j++)
            if (flag = a[j] != a[i]) {
                a[i + 1] = a[j];
                cP = ++j;
                break;
            }

        if (j == a.length) {
            for (int k = (i += flag ? 2 : 1); k < a.length; k++)
                a[k] = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you count the 12 lines ?

Comment: @MartinR "Not counting blank lines"

Comment: No, please *don't* start commenting your code like that. Just make the code itself readable. Comments on single lines of code are the start of code smell.

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, this solution is not following OOP paradigm, i know this homework is a short one, but i suggest to use object instead of static methods if possible.
- smoosh can be private
- int[] a is too short and means nothing
- Instead of stringInts(int[] ints) use Arrays.toString()
- cP is too short name.
- int i, j = 0 set j to 0 is not necessary
- Iteration at iteration looks like ... here is my version:

  ```
  private static void smoosh(int[] a) {
      int last = 0;
      int lastPosition = 0;
      int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);

      Arrays.fill(a, -1);

      for(int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
           if (i == 0 || last != copy[i]) {
               a[lastPosition++] = copy[i];
           }

           last = copy[i];
      }
  }
  ```

My suggestion is to learn Java API (and OOP), it has many built in functions ;)

Answer (score 1):

- just use a real unit test framework, such as JUnit, instead of writing your own test methods.
- define variables where they are needed to make your code more readable: `i` can be declared inside the loop: `for (int i = 0;`.
- if you use an integer flag instead of a boolean anyways, your if statement can be simplified to `i += 1 + flag;`.
- style: be consistent with where you place `{` (this would also save you two lines).
- always use curly brackets, even for one line statements (to avoid bugs and increase readability; for example, right now it's hard to see that your second `break` breaks out of the `i` loop).